# Why am I getting this JSON ajax error on line 1 column 1?

Tags: ajax, json

I am getting an error on this line:

var myObj = JSON.parse(url.responseText);

and I can't figure out why. Does anybody know? The user types a URL where the JSON file is located.

```
   function loadJson()  {
   var xmlhttp;
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest)  {
     xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   } else {
   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()  {

     if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
       var myObj = JSON.parse(url.responseText);
              var list = "<table border = '1'><tr><th>Name</th><th>Address</th><th>Major</th><th>GPA</th></tr>\n";

              for (var i = 0; i < myObj.students.length; i++)
              {
                   list  = list + "<tr><td>" + myObj.students[i].first + " " + myObj.students[i].last + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + myObj.students[i].address.city + ", " + myObj.students[i].address.state + " " +
                            myObj.students[i].address.zip + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + myObj.students[i].major + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + myObj.students[i].gpa + "</td></tr>\n";
               }
               document.getElementById("json").innerHTML = list;
     }
   }
   var url=document.getElementById("url").value;
   xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
   xmlhttp.send();
 }
```

Comment: Do a `console.log(url.responseText);` then check the console and you'll see why.

Comment: How do I do that? Do I type that into the console/debugger?

Comment: just before the line that gives the error.

Comment: Oh, is "responseText" undefined? I thought that was part of the method?

Comment: you defined url here `var url=document.getElementById("url").value;` , responseText is a property of the `XMLHttpRequest` object

Comment: Oh... Ok sorry I'm still new to this. Would I use something else instead? Doesn't JSON.parse need something to convert the url or something? I have no idea.

Comment: Never mind I GOT IT! I needed to do xmlhttp.responseText instead of url.responseText. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response text from the ajax request is a property of the `XMLHttpRequest` object

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()  {

    if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
        var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I canged var myObj = JSON.parse(url.responseText); to var myObj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText); and it works fine!